# GoogleService failed to initialize error when using mobile vision library of google

Tags: android, api

I am using google mobile vision library in my project for face detection, but i am not getting a box around the face in images. also in my logcat i am getting the error.

GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Why i am getting this error and how could i resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a google-services.json file in your project. Get it here.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file

Comment: Will i be needing a json file even if i am using an on device api?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that seems to be the case. What library have you included in the project? It is enough to use just the specific library, https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/package-summary

Comment: I have included mobile vision library.    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Comment: You can use 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0' instead. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: i am using that only

Comment: See "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" in the above link.